# Netflix-Zuul lingering ThreadLocal with RequestContext Filter

Tags: spring, tomcat, netflix-zuul

I recently came onto a project and was not part of implementing the Netflix-Zuul filter. I'm not totally sure what to include, and the rest of the team is also unfamiliar with Zuul.

There is some concern about a message in the catalina log upon shutdown in between deploys on our dev server. Thus far, I have been unable to find any guidance about what this message means, or where to begin solving it. Any guidance is appreciated as we are worried it will be a scalability issue. Please let me know what additional information I can provide that may help to track this down.

```
Jun 19, 2018 4:46:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [studentApp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext$1] (value [com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext$1@59d4a2ba]) and a value of type [com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in code, there's a ThreadLocal being created. Sounds like it's storing the RequestContext so that some other code can get at it without taking it as a parameter. That's probably not an ideal way to do that, but sometimes we do Bad Things to get things done on time.

If this were in a log for an app i worked on, i'd start searching for where the ThreadLocal gets created. Based on the log message, i'd start looking for:

```
new ThreadLocal<RequestContext>
```

somewhere in your code. You then need to figure out what refers to that, and maybe find somewhere to call remove() on it when you no longer need it. For example, there may be code that's setting it when a request is handled and not removing it at the end of request handling.

Comment: In this case, no instances of this happening are found. We are starting to wonder if it is an issue within the version of netflix-zuul we are using, but are having difficulty with getting the app to update. The threading model around it seems fine otherwise, just not the request context itself.

Comment: Ah, that's something inside zuul, got it.

https://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/context/RequestContext.html

So a bug in zuul, or someone is doing something with a value from the RequestContext that doesn't allow it to be removed later.